# How can I get a screenshot in headless ChromeDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, screenshot, headless

I am trying to capture screenshots in a headless ChromeDriver instance. I can get a proper screenshot without running headless.

I have tried to just follow an example for this, however, the example is not working properly.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.setBinary("/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");

            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
            driver.navigate().to("https://adobe.com");

            File srcFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            // Now you can do whatever you need to do with it, for example copy somewhere
            FileUtils.copyFile(srcFile, new File("testscreenshot.png"));
            driver.quit();

    }
```

The screenshot the code above generates will be blank white, with a scroll bar on the side. What can I do to capture a screenshot in headless mode? Is this possible?

Comment: windows i can see screenshot.Are you using windows or macOS?

Comment: I'm on MacOS...

Comment: can you add this options and check if it works. `chromeOptions.addArguments("window-size=1920,1080");`

Comment: I found a solution, and I will answer the question

Answer (score 0):

This behavior was different on Windows, Ubuntu, and Mac. I am currently working on Mac. It was not rendering the page for some reason. This was all I needed before I took my screenshot

`new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)`

Comment: Just instantiating a WebDriverWait object is not going to do anything (apart from increase your execution time very slightly).  I would suggest that correlation != causation in this instance.

Comment: Well, it made it work. The important part here is that behavior is different from expected on mac

Comment: I suggesting the tiny increase in execution time is probably what ended up having the page render, not the fact you instantiated an object.  Ideally you would use the explicit wait to wait for an expected element to appear, rather than just instantiating it.

Comment: It made it wait 10ms